# Is there a functioning wifi tool (not network manager) that works on public wifi and supports VPN?

Tags: network-manager, wicd

I have never managed to get network manager to work on any machine I have installed it on. Five machines desktops, laptops, netbooks and a tablet. WICD always works perfectly but WICD does not support public wifi or VPN. Is there a tool that allows VPN access and public wifi use on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what type of VPN you want to connect to, and they are not as integrated as NetworkManager. In my experience, **kvpnc** tends to work well and supports a few VPN systems, although it requires the installation of additional dependencies from a standard GNOME desktop because of QT and KDE libraries.

If you're having issues with NetworkManager, you definitely should report bugs and clearly explain what is not working for you, then we can look into the problem and possibly fix it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Dear Mathieu
Thank you for your reply. The problems I have are bugs that are widely reported. Network manager does not see wireless networks. On every machine I have put it on after every install of Ubuntu network Manager reports there are no wireless networks visible. If i remove network manager and install WICD then those networks are visible and accessible. If network manager and WICD are both installed then neither can see wireless networks. I am afraid I have on idea why it occurs, I think it is unlikely to be a driver issue. But if you Google WICD you find literally hundreds of "solved" wifi issues upon removal of network manager and installation of WICD. I should make clear, no other changes are required, no extra drivers or anything. This has been true in all version from me since 9.04 on 5 computers, laptop and desktop

In wired mode network manager works but corrupts required settings after circa one week. And therefore again in wired mode WICD is stable, network manager is not.

The problem is WICD is feature poor, no VPN and no ad hoc networks

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain what is going wrong. If your symptom is that your browser can open the first display from the local wifi, but gets "site not found" when trying to go to the login site (or when you hit "connect me"), then I have a suggested answer on another thread.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1084585/495717