# connection to wifi public fails after captive portal login, kubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu

On a fresh installed kubuntu 18.04, i cannot login properly to a public wifi that worked just fine with 16.04, and still works for other users around me on various hardware/os.

When i connect, I am redirected as expected to the public network authentication web page just fine.

I can then authenticate with credentials, but the problem starts there: the authentication doesn't stick, and i get an error after the login page redirects me (503, Http/1.1 Service Unavailable).

If i try to open another page, i still get redirected to public network login page, but keeps failing.

I looked up a bit for solution, but the issues i could find are more related to displaying the login page, which works just fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, answering to myself, maybe it can help someone else...

It turns out that the problem for me was apparently systemd resolvconf.
I tried to replace it with dnsmask, and boom, worked flawlessly.

I followed the method from that post: [How to disable systemd-resolved and resolve DNS with dnsmasq?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898605/how-to-disable-systemd-resolved-and-resolve-dns-with-dnsmasq)

Answer (score 2):

Getting to a wifi login page at hotspots

The Problem: The wifi icon on the top right shows '?' with no wifi connection. This is because you first need to reach that wifi network's log-on page in order to accept the terms and conditions etc. But no browser shows that page. Solution 1:

Settings > Privacy > connectivity Checking > Off.

The above is enough to show some log-in pages. Some however (e.g. gwr on-train wifi) *also* require solution 2:

Settings > Wi-Fi > select the settings (click the cog icon) for the network you are trying to reach. Go to the IPv6 tab. For IPv6 method select 'Automatic, DHCP only' (instead of the default setting 'Automatic'). Click Apply.

It may also help to do:

Settings > Network > Network Proxy - Off. (Click on the settings button with the cog icon on it.)

Comment: that wasn't the issue, the issue append after the authentication page. Meaning, the authentication page/form was opening, i was filling it up and submitting, and only then was i getting the issue. moving from resolvconf to dnsmask fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this, posted it on another thread

https://askubuntu.com/a/1084585/495717

Basic answer: supply alternative known, trusted DNS in the network-manager applet.