# Cannot connect to windows network

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm trying to connect to the Wi-Fi network at my college, but I have been unable to do so. I am running ubuntu 18.04 and the really weird part is that it connects perfectly fine when using Windows.

When I attempt to connect to the network, I enter my username and password, but it just keeps failing to connect, and asks me for my username and password again.

I have tried other answers mentioned on stackoverflow, but have had no luck. I have tried changing the authentication type, but still nothing. I have also tried forgetting the network and trying to login with my credentials again. And I have tried rebooting my computer. I have tried installing samba in hopes that something might just start working. But no matter what I do, it just does not want to work!

The network is set to WPA & WPA2 enerprise, and I select "No CA cert required".
Below is the output from `cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Edu-WiFi`:

```
[connection]
id=Edu-WiFi
uuid=2eea8b36-c534-4a49-bbe3-6e33b7ac448f
type=wifi
permissions=

[wifi]
mac-address=<retracted>
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=infrastructure
ssid=Edu-WiFi

[wifi-security]
auth-alg=open
key-mgmt=wpa-eap

[802-1x]
eap=ttls;
identity=<username>
password=<password>
phase2-autheap=mschapv2

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

Running `lspci` produces the following output for the network card (ethernet is not an option, since my laptop does not have an ethernet port):

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
```

]
If any other information is need, please let me now and I'll add it!

Any help in solving this problem will be greatly appreciated, since I'm not wanting to use Windows :D

Comment: This sounds like the seconds answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039314/connection-to-wifi-public-fails-after-captive-portal-login-kubuntu-18-04) might help you - they are manually setting the DNS server to one they know works (try 8.8.8.8)

Comment: @CharlesGreen I can't even connect to the network, so I'm not sure how DNS will change anything, but I will try that. Thank you! :D

Comment: Ah - you are connecting and entering credentials:  "..., I enter my username and password, but it just k..."