# Hotel Wifi problem on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: wireless, network-manager, 18.10

On Dell Latitude I run Ubuntu 18.10. Originally the wifi symbol had a question mark which I got rid of by switching off connectivity check in privacy settings. This didn't fix the problem. Network adapter is Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565/AR9565. This didn't happen previously on other wifi connections.

The webpages report error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, which I find quite weird. Restarting network connection doesn't fix it.

Comment: Have you gone to things like cnn.com or the hotel's landing page?  it sounds to me like you're stuck in a captive portal and need to accept the terms of connecting before it puts you into the Internet.  Do you use a non-standard DNS server in your configuration, or try to configure this manually without just doing straight DHCP with Network Manager and no manual configurations?

Comment: You cpuld be right. Currently ipv4 and ipv6 methods are set to automatic, so are dns and routes. Dns seever is thw same as ipv4 except for the fourth value. I didn't swt anything manually. Network proxy is off.

Comment: @ThomasWard OK this CNN/BBC trick worked. I guess this is how they inflate visitor counter))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Public Wifi in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034941/public-wifi-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 18.04 No WiFi adapter found \[Dell Inspiron 3542.\]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061539/ubuntu-18-04-no-wifi-adapter-found-dell-inspiron-3542)